# How to download MSI using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to use batch file to download a MSI installer from this link https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0win32_vs12-Release.msi.

I tried

```
bitsadmin /transfer "downloadingjob" https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0-win32_vs12-Release.msi C:\xxx\xxx.msi
```

but it gave the error

> 403:The client does not have sufficient access rights to the requested server
>   The error occurred while the remote file was being processed.

I also tried

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0-win32_vs12-Release.msi -OutFile C:\xxx\xx.msi"
```

and it said

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the security protocol in the PowerShell script as follows, And then have your invoke web-request command.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0-win32_vs12-Release.msi -OutFile D:\xx.msi
```

For the batch file you can have it something like below,

```
powershell -Command "& {[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0-win32_vs12-Release.msi -OutFile C:\xxx.msi;}"
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, actually I tried this before, and in .bat I guess I should use
powershell -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12"
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/releases/download/0.18.0/OpenSC-0.18.0-win32_vs12-Release.msi -OutFile C:\xxx\xxx.msi"
but it still gave the same error

Comment: I have updated the answer @WYK. Please check and verify. If it works please accept the answer

Comment: OH, it works. Though the interface looks a little bit difference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help @WYK